# クラウドサービスで SHA2 型式の SSL 証明書にマイグレートするため方法は?

Tags: azure

現在、以下のリンクにしたがい、sha1 型式の SSL 証明書を適用した環境があります。
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate/

SSL 証明書の有効期限が迫っているため、sha2 (SHA-256) 型式のものに変更しようと思います。

1. 前述のリンクのガイドと異なるのは、.csdef ファイルの thumbprintAlgorithm の指定のみで、値を "sha256" にすればよろしいでしょうか。
2. VIP スワップを使ってマイグレーションできますでしょうか。その際、新しい証明書 (中間証明書含む) を、管理ポータルでアップロードし、新しい証明書のサムプリント値で .csdef ファイルを作成すればよろしいでしょうか。
3. 管理証明書や RDP のパスワード等は sha256 で、新規に作成しなくてもよろしいでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

現状、クラウドサービスでサポートされているのはsha1のみで、sha256は使えないと思います。
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/gg465718.aspx

入れ替えの手順的には新しい証明書のアップロードと、新証明書を使ったパッケージ（RDPも含む）をデプロイしてVIPスワップで問題ないかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

.csdef で定義されている thumbprintAlgorithm は証明書のサムプリントの形式なので
SHA-256 証明書とは関係ない部分になります。サムプリントの形式は sha1 のままで問題無いです。

クラウドサービスでも問題なく SHA-256 な SSL 証明書を利用出来ることを、自己署名証明書ですが
確認が出来ました。これまでと同じように Visual Studio から設定可能です。

Comment: あー、そういう意味なんですね。通るならsha2でも良さそうですね。

Comment: 整理すると、以下のとおりということでしょうか。
1. SHA-256 証明書は、そのまま利用する。
2. .csdef で指定する、サムプリントのアルゴリズムは SHA1 を指定する。

Comment: そうですね。証明書の形式に関わらず、サムプリントは SHA1 になります。（このあたりは VS だとすべて面倒見てくれました）
後は kosmos.ebi さんの言うように証明書アップロード、デプロイ、VIP スワップで問題無いと思います。